# React Native crash when app starts on Android 14

Tags: android, react-native

The App crashes when running on `Android 14`, and the log of crash report platform is shown as the image. Did anyone meet this situation? Any advice will be appreciated.

- [Github Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/37769)
- [GitHub issue](https://github.com/RevenueCat/react-native-purchases/issues/670)

**dev environment**

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.3",
```

I have referenced those links but got no clues.

Comment: please add the crash log as text to your question

Comment: https://github.com/reactwg/react-native-releases <=0.69 Unsupported

Comment: how dd you resolve this?

Comment: same here if I change compile and targetSdkVersion to 34. I am on RN 0.71.11.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the only thing you can do to date is use react-native v0.73 no less version :c

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).